# Spinner doesn't work if is called from button

Tags: android, button, click, spinner

This is my code:

```
String[] spinnerPresets = { "Test", "Test1", "Test2" };
        final Spinner s1 = new Spinner(this);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, spinnerPresets);
        s1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        s1.setPrompt("Presets");
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int position, long arg3) {  
                        if(position==0) {
                            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        if(position==1) {
                            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "TEST1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        if(position==2) {
                            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "TEST2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    }
                });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View paramView) {
                s1.performClick();
            }
        });
```

When I click on button, it shows my spinner, but problem is that it doesn't show Toast message when I select some of these items in that spinner.

Comment: does it happen with all of the items in the spinner, or just some of them?

Comment: With all of them. There are 3 items in this case.

Comment: its not taking onitemselected event when the spinner is opened using a button.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't try but can you check this out.

```
        s1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
int positon;     
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

          positon = s1.getSelectedItemPosition();

                        if(position==0) {
                                Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        if(position==1) {
                            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "TEST1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        if(position==2) {
                            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "TEST2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                }
  }
    });
```

Comment: probably you have some other problem. coz I just copy the code from working project. tell me more what you doin exactly

Comment: You can see everything what I am  doing in my question, I know that it should work, but problem is that I open my spinner from button and if I open it from button it doesn't work.

Comment: is that working when you select spinner manually? (not from button)

Comment: probably performClick doesn't fire spinner's listener

Comment: can you try this one I just edtied.